# Getting weird results with bevel

Tags: modeling

My problem is when I try to use bevel (Ctrl+b) I get very strange results. I already tried to apply the scale. Please help. Thanks in advance.[image: There is a screenshot]

Comment: If the bevel works fine with a regular cube, maybe you have some hidden face or doubled vertex that was selected.

Comment: I double-checked I have all faces unhidden and do not have any doubles. This happens to every part of my mesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. The reason was I joined two meshes with different normals directions. I connected these different vertices so I get this result.